# NEAR Rest API: How to generate a sign URL with Batch Transactions?

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to generate a sign URL using the [NEAR API Rest Server](https://github.com/near-examples/near-api-rest-server)

This is the Sign URL API:-
[image]

--

I want to perform ***storage_deposit*** and ***nft_approve*** actions in a single transaction.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is not  designed to execute a set of methods right now, it can be improved.

Are you sure `storage_deposit` call is needed before every `nft_approve` action? I checked the [NFT standard implementation](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/near-contract-standards/src/non_fungible_token/approval/approval_impl.rs#L55), it allows user to attach deposit just on `nft_approve`.

Comment: [Storage Model](https://docs.near.org/docs/tutorials/contracts/nfts/marketplace#storage-management-model)

Whenever someone puts an NFT for sale, the marketplace needs to store that info which costs $NEAR. Users can either deposit as much NEAR as they want so that they never have to worry about storage again or they can deposit the minimum amount to cover 1 sale on an as-needed basis.

`storage_deposit` call is NOT needed before every `nft_approve` action, but needed at-least one time before `nft_approve` action. it depends on how much storage user has paid earlier.